# Delete the highlighted trailing space when double clicking a word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add parentheses around a highlighted word with a keyboard shortcut.

The default is to also select the trailing space after whatever word is double clicked which gives "(SelectedText )" instead of "(SelectedText)" and I have to manually delete the trailing space. This eliminates any convenience of auto adding the parentheses.

I have been given the code below.

```vb
Sub AddParens()
    Selection.InsertBefore "("
    Selection.InsertAfter ")"
End Sub

Sub SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace()
    Dim objWordSelected As Range
    Selection.Words(1).Select
    'Initialization
    Set objWordSelected = Selection.Range
    If objWordSelected.Characters.Last = Chr(32) Then
        objWordSelected.End = objWordSelected.End - 1
    End If
    objWordSelected.Copy
End Sub
```

This adds the parentheses but does not exclude the trailing space.

Comment: *asked 2 days ago*? If you are still here and the problem hasn't been solved yet, then I'll try.

This seems didn't make sence:  *...which always ends up giving me "(SelectedText )" instead of "(SelectedText)" ...*.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, just miss the [**SetRange**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.setrange) and [**Select**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.select) method:

```vb
Sub AddParens()
    Selection.InsertBefore "("
    Selection.InsertAfter ")"
End Sub
Sub SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace()
    Dim objWordSelected As Range
    Selection.Words(1).Select
    'Initialization
    Set objWordSelected = Selection.Range
    If objWordSelected.Characters.Last = Chr(32) Then
        objWordSelected.End = objWordSelected.End - 1
        objWordSelected.SetRange objWordSelected.Start, objWordSelected.End
        objWordSelected.Select
    End If
    objWordSelected.Copy
End Sub

rem By assigning this method to a quick key(shortcut) you can select the word where the cursor is located without a selection, and add parentheses before and after it and copy it.
Sub SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace_AddParens()
    SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace
    AddParens
End Sub
```

Or simplify the SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace with [**Selection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection) instead of [**Range**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range) *objWordSelected*:

```vb
Sub SelectWordAndRemoveTrailingSpace()
    With Selection
        .Words(1).Select
        If .Characters.Last = Chr(32) Then
            .SetRange Selection.Start, Selection.End - 1
        End If
        .Copy
    End With
End Sub
```